# Query parameters are persisting values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have to simulate a real-time data flow from the server, for that I have implemented a Timer class from the System.Threading namespace.

```
public class DataManager
{
    private Timer _timer;
    private AutoResetEvent _autoResetEvent;
    private Action _action;

    public DateTime TimerStarted { get; }

    public DataManager(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
        _autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        _timer = new Timer(Execute, _autoResetEvent, 0, 10000);
        TimerStarted = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public void Execute(object stateInfo)
    {
        _action();
        if ((DateTime.Now - TimerStarted).Seconds > 60)
        {
            _timer.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

And using this class to execute repository method to get latest data from controller.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] PagedTransactionDataRequest queryParams)
{
    var pageSize = queryParams.PageSize ?? 1;
    var pageNumber = queryParams.PageNumber ?? 10;

    <b>var timerManager = new DataManager(async () =>
    await _paymentDraftHub.Clients.All.SendAsync(SignalRConstants.TransferPaymentDraftServiceData, await _paymentTransactionRepository.GetAllDeclinedAsync(pageSize, pageNumber))
    );</b>

    var response = new ResponseMessage { Message = "Accepted", Code = "201" };
    return Ok(response);
}
```

PROBLEM: First request to the API is working perfectly fine but during the second request `pageSize` and `pageNumber` have the old values too. When the timer runs every 10 seconds, I can see the old query parameter values and new query parameter values both are getting executed.

I am not sure why the old values are even getting executed.

Comment: Just for clarity: you call your GET twice with different query params, and you expect your DataManager to update the query params after the first GET right?

Comment: @GuillaumeCR that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call your first GET, you create a DataManager. That DataManager only knows about the first query params. It then executes on a timer with those parameters.

When you call your second GET, you are creating a second DataManager. That second manager will also start executing on a timer with the 2nd set of parameters, but it does not affect the first one at all.

One solution is to make the DataManager a member of your controller, and expose the desired action as a property:

```
private DataManager _manager;

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] PagedTransactionDataRequest queryParams)
    {
        var pageSize = queryParams.PageSize ?? 1;
        var pageNumber = queryParams.PageNumber ?? 10;

if(_manager == null) {_manager = new DataManager(async () =>
        await _paymentDraftHub.Clients.All.SendAsync(SignalRConstants.TransferPaymentDraftServiceData, await _paymentTransactionRepository.GetAllDeclinedAsync(pageSize, pageNumber))
        );
}
else
{_manager.action = async () => await _paymentDraftHub.Clients.All.SendAsync(SignalRConstants.TransferPaymentDraftServiceData, await _paymentTransactionRepository.GetAllDeclinedAsync(pageSize, pageNumber));
}

        var response = new ResponseMessage { Message = "Accepted", Code = "201" };
        return Ok(response);
    }
```

I didn't have time to test this solution, so it may not even compile, but it does give you an idea.

Comment: so idea is to check if request already present then do not create object again and use existing. i will try this and let you know.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume for your direction, I have disposed timer before initializing it again and that is working fine.